# how to handle user changing query parameters in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, pagination, cursor

I have a listing site having a model with many properties on which I would like to use filters. I would like to use memcache and cursor for querying, e.g:

```
results=Model.all().filter("x =", a).filter("y =",b).with_cursor(cursor).fetch(20).
```

How should I handle cursor and pagination, when the user change the filter criteria, e.g.

```
from `x=a to x=c`?
```

Should I store cursor having key = query string? But then the query string changes with page numbers :( . I guess i will need to parse query string, remove page numbers and use that as a key for cursor. Is that how I should do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an "hash" of your current filter, and pass it to view. That can be stores there as an hidden field, like `<input type="hidden" name="prev_query" value="{{query_hash}}"/>`

On second request you'll check that current filter's hash equals to passed as parameter.

'Hash' maybe md5 of your filter params, or just join concatenation of them.

Comment: There's really no need to hash it - the user is submitting the query parameters with each request anyway. If you're going to do this, though, better to just store the cursor itself in the hidden field.

Comment: as I understand cursor is already stored and passed as parameter. The problem that query is changed, but we trying to use cursor from previous query. Isn't it?

Comment: @splix If the cursor is being passed around with the query, then there'll never be an opportunity to use the wrong cursor in the first place.

Comment: but if query is changes the we need to use an new cursor. passed cursor becomes invalid at this point

Comment: @splix Yes - but how is that a problem? A cursor for one query would be meaningless on another query anyway. Why would your users want to modify the query but remain on page x?

Comment: the problem that after changing query you need to throw out current cursor (and start from first page)

Answer (score 0):

Think of a cursor like a bookmark, holding place in a result set. Cursors are specific to the query they are for. You can't use the same cursor for two different queries - that would be akin to expecting a bookmark from one book to show you how far through you are in another.

If you want to store cursors elsewhere, you'll need to key them by the filter criteria so you can look up the appropriate one. Memcache is a poor choice, though, as elements may be evicted at any time. Why not just make the cursor part of the 'next page' URL?